# Is it possible to draw a rectangle with mouse to select multiple DIVs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to drag a rectangle with mouse to select those divs.

The selected div will change class from “no” to “yes”. Also, the `a` link is clickable and dblclickable

```
<div id= "container" >
    <div id="div-1" info="info1">
         <div class="no" id="inside">
             <a href="#">something</a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div-2" info="info2">
         <div class="no" id="inside">
             <a href="#">something</a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div-3" info="info3">
         <div class="no" id="inside">
             <a href="#">something</a>
         </div>
    </div>
    <div id="div-4" info="info4">
         <div class="no" id="inside">
             <a href="#">something</a>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you want is not a question. Please try to be more accurate and put some code inside your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the jQuery UI Selectable, the code adds a `yes` class to selected divs and adds the `no` class when a div is deselected. The code looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#container").on("selectableselected selectableunselected", function(){
     $(".inside").removeClass("yes").addClass("no");
     $(".ui-selected > .inside").removeClass("no").addClass("yes");
   });
});
```

(I had to change the `inside` id to a class since it uses multiple elements.)
The solution to anchor tags not working inside of selectable is here: https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4236